# ES6 way to bundle CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, import, ecmascript-6

I'm working through a React tutorial which uses old-school `require` syntax, and trying to update it to the more modern `import` syntax from ES6.

The tutorial suggests we start our JS file with the lines

`var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
require("./index.css");`

I've figured out that the first two lines should instead read

`import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`

but I'm stuck on the third line. What's the `import` version of requiring a CSS file?

(Normally I would just link the CSS in my HTML file - I assume the reason they're having us include it in the JS is so it will get minified and bundled? Are there other reasons?)

Comment: are you using the create-react-app command to create react app?

Comment: @Ikram-Ud-Daula No - that abstracts away all the details of webpack, npm, etc which I'd like to learn about, so I chose a tutorial which does it manually and explains everything. It's a great tutorial, but it's in ES5, so I'm trying to follow along and ES6-ify as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import` css just like anything else!

`import "/index.css";`

---

> *I assume the reason they're having us include it in the JS is so it 
>   will get minified and bundled?*

You're right! Importing CSS inside your module allows tools like Webpack to properly scour the dependency tree and include your CSS file.

Assigning a module name to your CSS import also allows for some neat features.

For example, if you assign a module name to your `import` as follow,

```
import stylesheet from './index.css';
```

you'll now be able to treat the class selectors inside your stylesheet as properties of the module name, which makes it easy to assign styles to your component's DOM.

For example, you can now do:

```
import stylesheet from './index.css';

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={stylesheet.myClassSelectorName}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the css modules version, you only do `import "/index.css";` to match their initial code.

Comment: Got it. Didn't realize CSS could be treated the same was as a JS module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just Import css in your file using  import "FilePath/FileName";